# visualising parametric equations

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, visualization

Whenever I'm doing a question on curves, and I am given the equation without the graph I can reasonably visualise in my head what that graph would look like, and for the more complicated equations, I can just put some values in and figure it out.

However, I can't do this for parametric equations and it puts me off answering the question if I don't know what the graph would look like.
if given a parametric equation in the form:

$x = f(t)$

$y = g(t)$

How can i tell what the graph would look like without having to start messing on with plotting points or algebraic manipulation, it doesn't have to be exact, just the generalised shape, (i.e. is it a circle? in what quadrant? Is it a quadratic curve? u or n? Is it a trigonometric graph?) and stuff like that so I can get a general idea for what I'm dealing with.
thanks in advance. (this is for A-level questions if that helps at all)

Comment: You can consider the roots and extrema of those functions. On a side note, no idea why you were downvoted. You should however aim to reason about curves even without a graph.

Comment: Try using the free program GeoGebra (www.geogebra.org) to plot parametric curves and get a feel for them. Type (cos(x), sin(x)) into the input line for example.

Comment: I can't exactly whip out my phone in the middle of an exam,  also thanks for the advice about the roots and extremes.

Comment: Obviously, you would gain some insight into parametric curves before the exam. Perhaps you could change your question to make it clear you are only talking about what you might do in the middle of an exam?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_sketching

Comment: Perfectly reasonable question which I share. It's easy to visualize certain particular equations, but if f, g, etc are complicated than things get trickier. I've found that practicing seeing curves from different angles or cross sections, then tweeking the equations and trying to predict how the curve will change helps. Graphing different curves in desmos/geogebra helps create stronger mental impressions of the shapes. Also, working through many problems with parametric equations makes it easier to visualize them, I think because the images are being invoked from different mental contexts.